# "Try Ubuntu" option is not displayed

Tags: 12.04, live-usb

I created a live USB using Unetbootin (distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 ) from the alternate installation ISO, but while booting "Try Ubuntu" option is not displayed in the Unetbootin menu. Is there any way to try this Ubuntu distribution without installing?

Comment: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.9.8.exe

Use this link to download a tool similar to Unetbootin. This may work a little better for you. This is the one recommended by Ubuntu on their website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you download the ISO for the Desktop release.  If you download the alternate ISO it does not have the LiveBoot "Try Ubuntu" or use the graphical installer.

To download the latest desktop release of the ISO go here:

[Download Ubuntu Desktop ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

In the first box select whether you want 32 bit (recommended) or the 64 bit release then click the "Start Download" button.

Comment: @ fabricator4 I'hv downloaded  ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent.

Comment: @hawk  that's why you cant see the 'try Ubuntu' option.  The alternate install disk is a non-graphical installer only.  You need to download the LiveDVD to be able to run the "try Ubuntu option.

Comment: @hawk I've modified the answer slightly and added a link to download the correct desktop release which will work as you want.

Comment: @fabricator4 Means ubuntu server doesn't have "Try ubuntu"? And then I can't repartion /dev/sda1 ?!