# downloaded 14.04 to a usb stick

Tags: boot

How do you boot from windows usb stick without it trying to install distro. The only way I could get the stick to boot was use wubi icon then it tries to install and ends up saying I don't have enough space.   I'm running  Windows Xp and ubuntu 10.10

Comment: [How do I try Ubuntu from a USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/q/261985) or [“Try Ubuntu” option is not dislayed](http://askubuntu.com/q/143119) should help. (Sorry about the confusion about what version you're using. You might want to edit your question to clarify that you're attempting *to install* 14.04, which is a supported release.)

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows this may help you..